# Android glide not loading pictures in Android 4.X

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am using Glide v4.11 to load pictures from the web , everything work fine in android 5.0 or higher but in android 4.X pictures do not load.

Here is my code :

```
 RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal)
                    .error(android.R.drawable.presence_offline)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);

   Glide.with(context)
                    .load(data.getImage_url())
                    .apply(options)
                    .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

and here is the LogCat on Android 4.4:

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https://www.gradientapi.xyz/generate/w/1000/h/500 with size [188x263]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb85422a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0xa744e990:0x00000000))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 cause:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb85422a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0xa744e990:0x00000000))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 cause:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb85422a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0xa744e990:0x00000000))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb85422a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0xa744e990:0x00000000)
```

I searched over web and i found that Android 4.4 only support TLS 1.0.

It may be the issue ? and if yes is there any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a handshake exception. On devices older than `Android 5.0` `TLSv1.1` and `TLSv1.2` protocols are not enabled by default and that's why this exception occurs.

You can try this inside your Application's class onCreate method:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 19) {
        try {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
```

Also, You can check [this github issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372) for better solutions.

Comment: I added the code in onCreate method and it work, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on API 30. It was weird, I was using Retrofit with okhttp just fine to access other things on the same server, but when I tried to use Glide to load an image, I got the dreaded:

```
SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0xe78f6a18: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
```

I saw various posts about much older Android versions having problems with TLS1.2 but that wasn't the issue. It seems like Glide has a dependency on an older version of OKHttp and that was the problem. Or something like that, not exactly sure, but I did fix it with this in my gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.12.0'
```

It seems like the `okhttp3-integration` is what fixes it. I'm posting this here for anyone else who gets stumped by this and does some searches.